# c++ strange variable values

Tags: c++, eclipse, variables

I have a code snippet that is just originating two `int` values for the first time. Here's the line of code:

```
int xb2,yb2 = 0;
```

But, according to the debugger, when it hits this line of code, the value of xb2 is `4262504`!

What could have caused this?

By the way, sorry if I am missing something obvious, I am new to C++.

Comment: Maybe, I think the latter one might be more likely. Thank for the input!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xb2` is set to `4262504` (some arbitrary value, usually whatever happened to be at that location on the stack beforehand) because you never initialized it to `0`.

The correct way to do it is

```
int xb2 = 0, yb2 = 0;
```

In addition, you state it's a strange value "when it hits this line of code". Make sure you actually *execute* that line in the debugger. If the cursor position or highlight is *on* that line, it usually means it's the one to be executed *next.* In other words, you may need to do one more step operation.

Comment: Oh okay :) I thought, coming from other languages, that doing what I did above would set both the values to zero. Thank you!

Comment: I just tested it, and it doesn't appear to be working.

Comment: @CodeCube, then you have a _separate_ issue, the code provided will initialise `xb2` just fine.

Comment: @paxdiablo why not write your own answer?

Comment: looks like for some odd reason I have to put an additional line below that saying xb2 = 0;

Comment: @NeilKirk, because my answer would basically be the same as this one, with some added stuff. Where the answer is essentially correct, I prefer just to clean it up if I think it could be phrased better. In the early days, I may have put up my own answer to do a bit of rep-seeking but it's hardly necessary now :-)

Comment: @CodeCube, if that's truly the case then either your compiler is seriously broken, or you're doing something else wrong that's not immediately obvious from the code posted. My bet's on the latter :-)

Comment: Probably, for now I will just add xb2 = 0; as a separate line because it works.

Answer (score 2):

Your code

```
int xb2,yb2 = 0;
```

is just setting the value 0 to yb2,

try this:

```
int xb2=0,yb2=0;
```